# How do you link multiple many-many relationships in EF Core 6 when there is only 1 bridge table?

Tags: many-to-many, hierarchy, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-6.0

Whether using annotation or Fluent API, linking 2 classes with a many-many join is pretty basic post EF Core 5.  That said, I can't for the life of me find anything for a bridge table with more than 2 objects.

In my specific case I have a product catalog 4 layers deep that use a single bridge table to represent a composite product.

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkaHn.png)

I cannot change the model as this is a cloud service designed this way, but I can't figure out how to code the dbContext to work without creating duplicates in the collections.

What I'm trying to build is where the entity for an Offering contains a collection of Specifications with a collection of Characters with a collection of Options.

I've tried using FluentAPI

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Offering>()
                .ToTable("sn_prd_pm_product_offering", schema: "dbo")
                .HasMany(x => x.Specifications as ICollection<Specification>)
                    .WithMany(x => x.Offerings as ICollection<Offering>)
                    .UsingEntity<ProdConfiguration>(
                        x => x.HasOne(x => x.specification as Specification)
                       .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.specification_id),
                        x => x.HasOne(x => x.offering as Offering)
                       .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.offering_id));
```

This works for a single parent / child but produces duplicates since there is a record for each of the grand children and great grandchildren.

This doesn't work at all:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProdConfiguration>()
                .ToTable("sn_prd_pm_product_offering_characteristic", schema: "dbo")
                .HasKey(pc => new { pc.offering_id, pc.specification_id, pc.characteristic_id, pc.option_id });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProdConfiguration>()
                .HasOne(x => x.offering as Offering)
                    .WithMany(x => x.Config).HasForeignKey(x => x.offering_id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProdConfiguration>()
                .HasOne(x => x.specification as Specification)
                    .WithMany(x => x.Config).HasForeignKey(x => x.specification_id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProdConfiguration>()
                .HasOne(x => x.characteristic as Characteristic)
                    .WithMany(x => x.Config).HasForeignKey(x => x.characteristic_id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProdConfiguration>()
                .HasOne(x => x.option as Option)
                    .WithMany(x => x.Config).HasForeignKey(x => x.option_id);
```